# Remove specific data from a Python pandas dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

We wrote this code in order to plot a charge spectrum like this (histo from HG (columun) for a specific CH (another column)):

[image]

This plot was obtained from a dataset, where in it there is a column named "Ts (ns)":

```
            CH    LG     HG  Ts(ns)  ToT(ns)
0         0.0  75.0   80.0     0.0      0.0
1         1.0  73.0   77.0     0.0      0.0
2         2.0  74.0   65.0     0.0      0.0
3         3.0  72.0   73.0     0.0      0.0
4         4.0  74.0   74.0     0.0      0.0
...       ...   ...    ...     ...      ...
2613307  59.0  75.0   74.0     0.0      0.0
2613308  60.0  76.0  106.0   811.5     10.5
2613309  61.0  75.0   75.0     0.0      0.0
2613310  62.0  76.0   73.0     0.0      0.0
2613311  63.0  74.0  100.0     0.0      0.0
```

Our goal is to remove, from the plot, ONLY the data that have a "Ts" different from "-". The code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import re
import numpy as np
import os
from tqdm import tqdm, trange

print(''' 

        _____                   _   _       _       _                    
       |  __ \                 | | | |     (_)     | |                   
       | |__) | ___   __ _   __| | | |      _  ___ | |_     _ __   _   _ 
       |  _  / / _ \ / _` | / _` | | |     | |/ __|| __|   | '_ \ | | | |
       | | \ \|  __/| (_| || (_| | | |____ | |\__ \| |_  _ | |_) || |_| |
       |_|  \_\\___|  \__,_| \__,_| |______||_||___/ \__|(_)| .__/  \__, |
                                                           | |      __/ |
                                                           |_|     |___/ 


''')


names = ['CH','LG','HG','Ts(ns)','ToT(ns)']
righe_primo_header = 5
righe_header = 5
canali = 64

# input file
infile = 'Run1_list_14_03_2022.txt' 

# determinare numero di righe, poi di eventi nel file di input
stream = os.popen('wc -l '+ infile)
nrighe = stream.read()
match = re.match(r"\s*(\S+) (.*)", nrighe, re.I)
items = match.groups()
nrighe = float(items[0])

# numero di blocchi di dati da leggere
ntrigger = (nrighe - righe_primo_header) / (canali + righe_header) - 1
ntrigger = int( ntrigger)
print('\nNel file sono stati trovati ',ntrigger,' eventi.\n')
ncanali_histo = int(np.sqrt(ntrigger))

ncanali_histo = 4096

events = []

file1 = open( infile, 'r')
for line in range(righe_primo_header-1):
    line = file1.readline()

line=file1.readline()
pbar = tqdm(total=ntrigger)
for trigger in range(ntrigger):

    for lineh in range(righe_header):
        line = file1.readline()
        #print('saltiamo ',line)
    for canale in range(canali):
        line = file1.readline()
        #print(' elaboriamo ',line)
        match = re.match(r"(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+", line, re.I)
        temparray = []
        if match:
            items = match.groups()
         
            for colonna in range(len(items)):
                col = items[colonna]
                if col == '-':
                    valore = 0
                else:
                    valore = float(items[colonna])
                temparray.append(valore)

        events.append(temparray)
    pbar.update(1)
                
file1.close()

df = pd.DataFrame( events, columns = names)
print('\nIl dataframe totale è il seguente:\n', df)

# istogramma di HG per canale fissato
plot_df = df.loc[ (df['CH'] == 44) | (df['CH'] == 13)| (df['CH'] == 19) | (df['CH'] == 50) ]

print('\nIl dataframe selezionato è il seguente:\n', plot_df)

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn' permette di sovrascrivere il dataframe.


plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==13] -= (99.2910)  
plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==13] /= (33.1946)    #effettua una prima calibrazione
plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==13] += (1)  

plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==19] -= (99.2910)  
plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==19] /= (34.2973)    #effettua una prima calibrazione
plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==19] += (1)  

plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==44] -= (99.0216)  
plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==44] /= (32.8129)    #effettua una prima calibrazione
plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==44] += (1) 

plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==50] -= (98.1520)  
plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==50] /= (34.1027)    #effettua una prima calibrazione
plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==50] += (1)  


layout = go.Layout(
    title="Equalized HG Multiphoton Spectrum",
    xaxis=dict(
        title="#p.e."
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title="Counts"
    ) ) 


fig3 = go.Figure(layout=layout)

fig3.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==13],name='CH 13'))
fig3.update_traces(xbins=dict(start=0, end=10, size=1/33.1946)) #gain canale 13
fig3.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==19],name='CH 19'))
fig3.update_traces(xbins=dict(start=0, end=10, size=1/34.2973)) #gain canale 19
fig3.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==44],name='CH 44'))
fig3.update_traces(xbins=dict(start=0, end=10, size=1/32.8129)) #gain canale 44
fig3.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=plot_df['HG'][df['CH']==50],name='CH 50'))
fig3.update_traces(xbins=dict(start=0, end=10, size=1/34.1027)) #gain canale 50

fig3.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', gridcolor='black')
fig3.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', gridcolor='black')
fig3.update_layout(barmode='stack') #per il cumulativo
#fig3.update_layout(barmode='overlay') #per i plot singoli



fig3.update_layout({
'plot_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
'paper_bgcolor': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
})

fig3.show()

"""

evento = 3

plot_df2 = df[(canali * evento):(canali*evento + canali)]

print('Il dataframe per lo scatter plot HG vs Ch relativo all evento ',evento, 'è il seguente: ', plot_df2)

fig2 = px.scatter(plot_df2, x='CH', y='HG', title='HG vs CH event ' + str(evento) )
fig2.show()

"""
```

Meanwhile the file is uploaded here: https://mega.nz/file/E1oEwLjD#PQcIiRrSDJD9LT4enrN1bQoWLmKpUTzBZLWVylVn_7g

How we can do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `data that have a "Ts" different from "-".` The question is what is "-"?

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete them basing on boolean conditions. In your case this should work:

```
df = df[df['Ts(ns)'] != '-']  # or change the '-' with the value you want filter on
```

You can have a look at [this](https://datascienceparichay.com/article/pandas-delete-rows-based-on-column-values/) for more as a reference.